# Spacy pos tagging PPER

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy, pos-tagger

I'm trying to make spacy tag a german word with `PPER`. See https://spacy.io/api/annotation. Here is my code:

```
import de_core_news_sm

nlp = de_core_news_sm.load()

tokenized = nlp("Der Mann liebt Kuchen.")
for token in tokenized:
    print(token, token.pos_, token.ent_type_)
```

Which string do I need to enter to get a `PPER` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for `PPER` `tag_` rather? Try `ich` or `sie`:

```py
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("de_core_news_md")
doc = nlp("Ich liebe mich. Sie liebt Dich.")

for tok in doc:
    print(f"{tok.text:<10} {tok.tag_:<10} {tok.pos_:<10}")
Ich        PPER       PRON      
liebe      VVFIN      VERB      
mich       PPER       PRON      
.          $.         PUNCT     
Sie        PPER       PRON      
liebt      VVFIN      VERB      
Dich       PPER       PRON      
.          $.         PUNCT
```

Answer (score 1):

`PPER` indicates to non-reflexive personal pronoun according to https://spacy.io/api/annotation#pos-de . Now, lets look at what is **reflexive personal pronoun** - it is part of speech where the word reflects back at the subject (ref. https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/pronouns-reflexive.htm). Therefore, non-reflexive personal pronoun is the word which do not refer to the subject.

**Personal pronouns** - I, you, he, she, it, we they, me, him, her, us, and them are all personal pronouns.

**Non-reflexive**: Ich sehe dich im Spiegel — I see you in the mirror.

**Reflexive**: Ich sehe mich im Spiegel — I see myself in the mirror.

However, SpaCy outputs same for both sentences.

```
text       tag        pos

Ich        PPER       PRON      
sehe       VVFIN      VERB      
dich       PRF        PRON      
im         APPRART    ADP       
Spiegel    NN         NOUN
```

Comment: I looked into this and it turns out that the docs are slightly wrong here. The docs have the standard STTS definition of `PPER`, but TIGER (the training data for this model) uses a modified definition where `PPER` is used if the pronoun can be replaced with an NP. For either definition, this is a difficult distinction for the model to learn (and the corpus also contains mostly 3rd person pronouns), so the performance for `PRF` vs `PPER` will probably not be very good for examples like this.